# Read JSON file in Python Pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have the following part of a JSON file:

```
[{"Date":"2020-02-17","Rt_low":0.5,"Rt_avg":1.93,"Rt_up":4,"population":"hosp"},{"Date":"2020-02-18","Rt_low":0,"Rt_avg":1.74,"Rt_up":4,"population":"hosp"}]
```

I want to read this in Python Pandas as a dataframe with the 4 columns as headers:

```
L = ['Date','Rt_low','Rt_up','population']
```

I tried the  following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_json(file_name, lines=True))
```

Which gives me a [1 rows x 235 columns] for the whole dataset. I want to get 4 columns dataframe. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may try this approach.

```
import pandas as pd
dataframe = pd.read_json('sample_json_file.json', orient='values')
print(dataframe)
```

output for the final dataframe will be one that consists of a header row, and two observations.

Answer (score 0):

I just did by:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_json(file_name))
```