# Python organising data From TXT and writing to csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data dump in this format:

```
[
{
      "vaultId": "429d60edc11df0a576cd9173e8c0d0de8792538862db0122848b87a96ecdf537",
      "loanSchemeId": "MIN150",
      "ownerAddress": "df1q7crh6d3dscj3sajpklehpnwdwhvs0l0jm9fr7s",
      "state": "inLiquidation",
      "liquidationHeight": 1488540,
      "batchCount": 2,
      "liquidationPenalty": 5,
      "batches": [
        {
          "index": 0,
          "collaterals": [
            "282.34948388@DFI"
          ],
          "loan": "6.38045570@BABA"
        },
        {
          "index": 1,
          "collaterals": [
            "300.16175126@DFI"
          ],
          "loan": "0.26745972@GOOGL"
        }
      ]
    },
]
```

which I have written to a txt, I am trying to use Pandas to make a dataframe and then write to csv using this code however I am reciving this error`ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 1729 elements, new values have 5 elements`. This is the code I have used to form the dataframe many thanks in advance.

```py
import pandas as pd
import simplejson as json

df = pd.read_json('auctions.txt')
df[['index', 'collaterals', 'loan']] = df.batches.apply(pd.Series)
```

Edit:
This is my error with changed code

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\iones\Documents\DeFI Chain Auction Bot\start.py", line 3, in <module>
    df = pd.read_json('auctions.json')
  File "C:\Users\iones\Documents\DeFI Chain Auction Bot\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 207, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\iones\Documents\DeFI Chain Auction Bot\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\iones\Documents\DeFI Chain Auction Bot\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py", line 614, in read_json
    return json_reader.read()
  File "C:\Users\iones\Documents\DeFI Chain Auction Bot\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py", line 748, in read
    obj = self._get_object_parser(self.data)
  File "C:\Users\iones\Documents\DeFI Chain Auction Bot\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py", line 770, in _get_object_parser
    obj = FrameParser(json, **kwargs).parse()
  File "C:\Users\iones\Documents\DeFI Chain Auction Bot\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py", line 885, in parse
    self._parse_no_numpy()
  File "C:\Users\iones\Documents\DeFI Chain Auction Bot\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py", line 1140, in _parse_no_numpy
    loads(json, precise_float=self.precise_float), dtype=None
ValueError: Expected object or value
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read JSON file in Python Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64348832/read-json-file-in-python-pandas)

Comment: are the two commas between some keys intended? If it was an accident then Anderson is right.

Comment: I've tried using the solution and I'm getting this error now : ValueError: Expected object or value. I changed the file type to json and used the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by using this

```
def jsontocsv():
    df = pd.read_json('auctions.json')
    df = df.explode('batches')
    df[['index', 'collaterals', 'loan']] = df.batches.apply(pd.Series)
    print(df[['vaultId', 'liquidationHeight', 'index', 'collaterals','loan']])
    df.to_csv('auctions.csv')
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Load the JSON using `read_json` and then convert the batch dictionary into columns

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json('data.json')
df[['index', 'collaterals', 'loan']] = df.batches.apply(pd.Series)
```

If you want the collaterals in separate rows

```
df = df.explode('collaterals')
```

Output

```
print(df[['vaultId', 'liquidationHeight', 'index', 'collaterals', 'loan']])

                                             vaultId  liquidationHeight  index        collaterals              loan
0  6af21886adcb92c4669a8a901975eb9b9d5544c67e4292...            1489770      0  2326.00000000@DFI  2.24978028@GOOGL
1  6af21886adcb92c4669a8a901975eb9b9d5544c67e4292...            1489770      1  2326.00000000@DFI  2.24978028@GOOGL
```

EDIT:

According to what you have said, it looks like the data is corrupt i.e. in an invalid JSON format. Please correct it at source. I have used the below data sample.

```
{
  "vaultId": "6af21886adcb92c4669a8a901975eb9b9d5544c67e429267841491649810958a",
  "ownerAddress": "df1qhh9ek2d98mxjeh58xdsfj7ad2k7q4d4kwshsxr",
  "liquidationHeight": 1489770,
  "batchCount": 2,
  "batches": [
    {
      "index": 0,
      "collaterals": [
        "2326.00000000@DFI"
      ],
      "loan": "2.24978028@GOOGL"
    },
    {
      "index": 1,
      "collaterals": [
        "2326.00000000@DFI"
      ],
      "loan": "2.24978028@GOOGL"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I've tried this just now and getting this error: 'ValueError: Expected object or value'

Comment: Add the full traceback/error to your post.

Comment: just updated the post

Comment: I think it was in the correct format have re pasted it, this document is quite large and I have  only included part of it however the rest is the same with different values.

Comment: Does the file start with a list `[` or just `{`

Comment: starts with a [

Comment: Yeah. Of course, it does. You haven't mentioned it anywhere and expect us to get an answer. It is totally different question now. Please refrain from such practices. @ionescuv

Comment: I have redone it with your code and the data you used and its the same error. 'ValueError: Columns must be same length as key'